# The map does not work at the beginning of going to the page, but works if it works refresh page in vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js

The map does not work at the beginning of going to the page, but works if it works refresh page in Vue.js.

Is there any help in this matter?

this code

```
mounted() { 
    this.geolocate();
},
methods: {

    async geolocate() {
        this.getFloatDirections();
        this.center = {
            lat: this.lat,
            lng: this.lng
        };
        this.coordinates = {
            full_name: this.$route.query.name,
            lat: this.lat,
            lng: this.lng
        };
        // console.log("typeof(this.center.lat)"+typeof(this.$route.params.lat))
    },
    getFloatDirections(){
        this.lat = parseFloat(this.$route.params.lat);
        this.lng = parseFloat(this.$route.params.lng);
    },
    getPosition: function(marker) {
        return {
            lat: marker.lat,
            lng: marker.lng
        };
    },
    toggleInfo: function(marker) {
        this.infoPosition = this.getPosition(marker);
        this.infoContent = marker.full_name;

        this.infoOpened = true;
    }
}
```

this image before refresh
[image: before refresh]

this image after refresh

[image: after refresh]

Comment: try use `created` hook instead of `mounted`. Refresh is equivalent to rerender the component

Answer (score 0):

Replace `mounted()` by `created()`

`mounted()` is called after DOM has been mounted so you can access the reactive component, templates, and DOM elements and manipulate them.

If you need to know more about vue [Lifecycle Hooks](https://alligator.io/vuejs/component-lifecycle/).